# How to Ignore T-SQL Print Statements when Using PHP SQLSRV_QUERYs

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

We are in the process of converting some PHP 5.3 internal API code to PHP 7.2.  Part of the conversion process is switching from using mssql_* DB APIs to using sqlsrv_* DB API.  One thing we have found is that the old MSSQL_EXECUTE statement ignores any T-SQL Print statements we have in our stored procedures but the new SQLSRV_QUERY statement does not.

For example, I have the following sample stored procedure:

```
create procedure spTestPrintStmt
  @var1 varchar(50),
  @var2 varchar(50),
  @var3 varchar(50),
  @rtn1 varchar(50) out,
  @rtn2 varchar(50) out
as
begin

  print 'Starting spTestPrintStmt...';

  print 'Vars: ' + @var1 + ',' + @var2 + ',' + @var3;

  select @rtn1 = @var1, @rtn2 = @var2 + @var3;

  print 'Returned: ' + @rtn1 + ',' + @rtn2;

  return 0;
end;
go
```

I use the following PHP page to test the above stored procedure:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stored Proc Param Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
<?php
  $result = 0;
  $var1 = 'abc';
  $var2 = 'def';
  $var3 = 'ghi';
  $rtn1 = '';
  $rtn2 = '';

  $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>'database', "UID"=>'username', "PWD"=>'password');
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect("dbserver", $connectionInfo);
  if( $conn === false ) {
    echo "Couldn't connect to SQL Server on dbserver.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  } else {
    echo "Connected!";
  }
  echo '<br/>'; 


  $tsql = "{ ? = call spTestPrintStmt(?,?,?,?,?) }";

  $params = array(
    array($result, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
    array($var1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($var2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($var3, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($rtn1, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
    array($rtn2, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT)
  );

  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);
  if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error in executing stored proc.";  
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
    echo "<br/>";
  }
  sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);  
  echo "Result: " . $result . "<br/>";
  echo "Rtn1: " . $rtn1 . "<br/>";
  echo "Rtn2: " . $rtn2 . "<br/>";

  sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
  sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
    </p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

When I run the above, I get the following results:

```
Connected!
Error in executing stored proc.Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Starting spTestPrintStmt... [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Starting spTestPrintStmt... ) )
```

Is there any way around this?  We use print statements extensively in our T-SQL code to aid with debugging.

Comment: I understand using PRINT to help debugging but why are they not commented out in production code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a look at the PHP docs for [sqlsrv_errors()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php), it states:

> By default, warnings generated on a call to any SQLSRV function are
>   treated as errors. This means that if a warning occurs on a call to a
>   SQLSRV function, the function returns FALSE. However, warnings that
>   correspond to SQLSTATE values 01000, 01001, 01003, and 01S02 are never
>   treated as errors. For information about changing this behavior, see
>   sqlsrv_configure() and the WarningsReturnAsErrors setting.

Therefore, your print statements (which seem to be treated as warnings) are being returned as errors. If you go to the linked [sqlsrv_configure()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-configure.php) function docs, you'll see an option.

I added the following line just before the connection is made:

```
sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors",0);
```

Now when I run your code, I no longer get an error. I get the following:

```
Connected!
Result: 0
Rtn1: 
Rtn2:
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.  Never thought that the print text being returned would be considered as warnings or errors.