# Problem in executing Stored Procedure on SQL Server Via PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm running the following code:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$affiliateId = 0;
$month = 10;
$year = 2023;
$groupid = 17;
$search = '';

$procedure_params = array(
    array(&$affiliateId, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$month, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$year, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$groupid, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$search, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
);

$sql = "EXEC [dbo].[smart_getAffiliateLeadListSearch] @AffiliateId = ?, @month = ?, @year = ?, @groupId = ?, @search = ?";

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $procedure_params);


if( !$conn ) {
    echo 'Connection error<br>';
    die( '<pre>'.print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true).'</pre>');
} else if( !$stmt ) {
    echo 'Statment error<br>';
    die( '<pre>'.print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true).'</pre>');
} else if( sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ) === false ) {
    echo 'Execution error<br>';
    die( '<pre>'.print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true).'</pre>');
}
```

I'm getting the following output

```
Execution error

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01000
            [SQLSTATE] => 01000
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Oct  1 2023 12:00AM
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Oct  1 2023 12:00AM
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01000
            [SQLSTATE] => 01000
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Nov  1 2023 12:00AM
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Nov  1 2023 12:00AM
        )

)
```

I don't understand the errors. it seems the error messages are just dates.
I'd love some help.

I've tried different Syntax for the query (with and without brackets, with and without the prepending [dbo]).
I've tried using the sqlsrv_prepare as well as sqlsrv_query. got almost the same results.

I'm expecting to get data but the sqlsrv_execute keep giving me errors.

Comment: Sounds like it's outputting PRINTs perhaps? or there's some raiserror inside the code?

Comment: It's supposed to output rows of data, but is doesn't get there. the sqlsrv_execute return false and the errors, as you can see, gives me nothing to go on.... only dates.

Comment: also, I don't know what a raiserror is :) so I might've not understood your comment.

Comment: if you run the output manually in management studio or something, what kind of messages / results do you get

Comment: Thank you very much @siggemannen. I'm the PHP guy, but thanks to your comment I asked the one who wrote the stored procedure if he prints anything and he did. he commented it and everything works now :) I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Great! you might wanna look here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082109/how-to-ignore-t-sql-print-statements-when-using-php-sqlsrv-querys and change your setting so someone adding PRINTs doesn't inadvertently mess up your logic

Comment: @Charlieface fyi, PHP's [sqlsrv_prepare function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) uses `?` placeholders.